# Regex: Replace all except numbers, specific characters and specific words

Tags: python, regex

If I have text like this:

```
    CARBON                                                               1569
    1.00% IRON                                                           234
    99% CARBON, 1% IRON                                                  181
    98.2% CARBON 1% ZINC                                                 181
    99% CARBON#1% IRON                                                   141
    ASD CARBON 2% IRON RANDOMWORD                                        23
```

Let's say I want to retain only the element names and percentage values (which includes **numbers, decimal point and percentage sign**). I can run a regex substitution to do so. I tried out plenty of combinations of stuff like `(CARBON|IRON|ZINC)`, which **replaces** all occurences of element names, and `[^0-9.\%]+` which **retains** all percentage values.

But I can't figure out how to combine these such that I **retain** both the percentage values and element names. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The spaces would also need to be retained for the output to make sense. All unnecessary characters can be replaced by spaces. The expected output would be

```
    CARBON                                                               1569
    1.00% IRON                                                           234
    99% CARBON  1% IRON                                                  181
    98.2% CARBON 1% ZINC                                                 181
    99% CARBON 1% IRON                                                   141
        CARBON 2% IRON                                                   23
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava: I've edited the question to include the expected output

Comment: now when you say "replace", you actually want to remove/replace everything except the percentages and element names. Also, the output data, while "cleaned" still looks super messy. What is the python code you use currently, and what structure should the data appear in after you're done? Because I doubt you want the data to be in a messy txt format like this, right?

Comment: @tst: True, but it's not difficult to replace multiple spaces by a single space, and to lstrip and rstrip to remove leading and trailing spaces, so I'd be okay with the output as mentioned in the question

Comment: @ShirishKulhari: If you don't care about spaces then you may use this: https://regex101.com/r/J1blnm/1

Comment: @ShirishKulhari what I wanted to get at is, instead of removing the data that does not equal (CARBON|IRON|ZINC) or [^0-9.\%]+, you could search for them and store them in a different datatype, like list of tuple and the print/write them in a structured way to a file. If you want to do any further operations with it, that would safe you a step as well, since you already have the data structured for the next operation

Comment: @anubhava: That does the trick. Instead of `\1` I can just replace by `\1 `, which is also good enough. You can write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match your desired text:

```
\b(CARBON\b|IRON\b|ZINC\b|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:%|\b))|\S
```

And replace it by `'\1 '` (will add trailing spaces in input lines)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J1blnm/1/)

**RegEx Detail:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `CARBON\b`: Match `CARBON` followed by word boundary
  - `|`: OR
  - `IRON\b`: Match `IRON` followed by word boundary
  - `|`: OR
  - `ZINC\b`: Match `ZINC` followed by word boundary
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`: Match an integer or float number
  - `(?:%|\b)`: Followed by `%` or word boundary
- `)`:
- `|`: OR
- `\S`: Match a non-whitespace character

Answer (score 1):

To simplify you May start with this as per your requirement:

```
\b(?!CARBON|ZINC|IRON)[a-zA-Z#]+
```

Then you may have to post process something (like # being replaced by blank) as per your comments.

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/U9789W/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing all the words except:
* Element names
* Numbers
* Percentage.

To achieve this you can use negative lookahead:

```py
(?!CARBON|IRON|ZINC|(\d+\.\d+\%)|\d+)\b[a-zA-Z#]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ek67Z/2)